# How to save history within UpdatePanel?

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, history

I created an admin page for a web application, and it's mostly ajax. Almost all the events in the page update one of the UpdatePanels on the page.
How can I save each UpdatePanel state in the user's history so when the user pushes the browser "back" button they wont get redirected to the login screen ?

Answer (score 5):

The ability to manage history was added in .NET 3.5 SP 1. Here are some resources that will help get you up to speed.

[Introduction to ASP.NET Ajax History](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-242.aspx)

[ASP.NET Podcast Show #117 - Using the History Functionality with the ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel in .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 Beta 1](http://aspnetpodcast.com/CS11/blogs/asp.net_podcast/archive/2008/06/15/asp-net-podcast-show-116-using-the-history-functionality-with-the-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-in-net-3-5-service-pack-1-beta-1.aspx)

[ASP.NET Podcast Show #119 - Using the History (Back) Functionality with the ASP.NET AJAX Web Services in .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 Beta 1](http://aspnetpodcast.com/CS11/blogs/asp.net_podcast/archive/2008/07/01/asp-net-podcast-show-119-using-the-history-back-functionality-with-the-asp-net-ajax-web-services-in-net-3-5-service-pack-1-beta-1.aspx)