# Browser back button with update panels

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, back-button

In an asp.net/c# application, I have an update panel on my main page. And everything on the page is updated via the update panel.

So there is only one page and all the changes are made in update panels using asynchronous postback (partial postback)

My question is: Is there a way to make the browser BACK button works and return the page to it's previous state?

Hope I was clear

Thank you very much for any help

more info: I tried to implement this http://rchern.wordpress.com/2008/05/11/updatepanel-backforward-browser-navigation/ but I wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is often a problem you could look at the resources mentioned in the answer to this question:

[How to save history within UpdatePanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365060/how-to-save-history-within-updatepanel)