# Enable browser back button for repeater control with update panel in asp.net c# with master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have page Searchbook.aspx which have 3 dropdowns and one repeater control which have button when i navigate to another page through that button to another page .when i click the back button of browser first page get default values instead of searched values. i want to restore the searched values.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9228298/217757

Comment: It does't have master page so script manager is defined there and event defined there should be defined in master page only but i want this functionality on searchbook.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can switch on the history of the browser for update panel requests by setting the switch `EnableHistory=true` in the `ScriptManager`.

Here is a code sample that might help...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server"
       EnableHistory="true"
       OnNavigate="scm_Navigate"
       />
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Click Me!"
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the source: http://aspnetpodcast.com/CS11/blogs/asp.net_podcast/archive/2008/06/15/asp-net-podcast-show-116-using-the-history-functionality-with-the-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-in-net-3-5-service-pack-1-beta-1.aspx

**UPDATE**
You can also use this method for adding a history point in browser.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.addhistorypoint(v=vs.100).aspx

Maybe this answer on SOF can also help...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/365746/217757

**UPDATE 2**
This blog post from Scott Gu sums it all...
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Enabling-Back_2F00_Forward_2D00_Button-Support-for-ASP.NET-AJAX-UpdatePanel

Comment: This is tried but not working because my script manager is on master page

Comment: Tim Schmelter and naveen Please help me i am struck here

Comment: history.AddEntry(contentList.SelectedIndex.ToString(); is giving error(refrence not found)

Comment: Have you read the text of Scott's blog. He is referencing another post and in that post another guy has created a control that maintains history...

Comment: to solve this problem i have used session to store the values on button click and on return assign the session values to the require field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the searched values on browser back button, then there are two ways to solve.

1. Keep the filter values selected by user in ViewState.
   => In this case always bind you data by implementing conditions which get from viewstate.
2. Or keep the values for filter data in query string.
   => In this case when user selected filter criteria put values in query string and bind data by putting condition with value fetched from URL query string.

Both above process can solve your purpose but the second one will be efficient and fast as putting values in Viewstate will slow down page.

Please let me know if I am not able to get you issue properly.

Update - 
You can use Viewstate method as you are using update panel and using query string make page refresh.

Viewstate is same as using Session variable, please see below code.

1. Add value in viewstate

   ViewState.Add("filter1", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
2. Get value from viewstate

   string getvalue = ViewState["filter1"].ToString();

So when after selecting filter criteria when click on submit button set value in viewstate and on page load get the same value and bind your control using those values.

Comment: Can you provide the example

Comment: @PrateekSingla I have updated my answer with sample code as you required. I missed to see about update panel so in your case viewstate will work. You can also use session if you don't want to use viewstate. Logic will be same just the medium of carrier of filter values is your choice.

Comment: how can we add a repeater control to session variable or view state